# Javascript textContent on Node doesn't return a unicode character

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Javascript textContent on Node doesn't return a unicode character

If I have a Node with unicode characters like this one, how can I get it back using textContent or other methods?

```js
console.log(
  document.createTextNode('a\u200eb').textContent
)
```

Comment: ... are you sure it is `'\u200'` and not `'\u0200'` because the latter used within your example as `'a\u0200eb'` does perfectly output `"aȀeb"`

Answer (score 0):

... are you sure it is `'\u200'` and not `'\u0200'` because the latter used within your example as `'a\u0200eb'` does perfectly output `"aȀeb"` ...

```js
console.log(
  'a\u200eb',
  ' versus ',
  'a\u0200eb'
);

console.log(
  document.createTextNode('a\u200eb').textContent,
  ' versus ',
  document.createTextNode('a\u0200eb').textContent
);


console.log(
  escape('a\u0200eb_%yz')
);
console.log(
  escape('a\u0200eb_%yz')
    .replace((/%u/g), '\\u')
    .replace((/%/g), '\\u00')
);

console.log(
  escape(
    document.createTextNode('a\u0200eb_%yz').textContent
  )
);
console.log(
  escape(
    document.createTextNode('a\u0200eb_%yz').textContent

  ).replace((/%u/g), '\\u').replace((/%/g), '\\u00')
);

console.log(
  "('a\\u0200eb_\\u0025yz' === 'aȀeb_%yz') ? ",
  ('a\u0200eb_\u0025yz' === 'aȀeb_%yz')
);
console.log(
  "('a\\u0200eb_\\u0025yz' === 'a\\u0200eb_%yz') ? ",
  ('a\u0200eb_\u0025yz' === 'a\u0200eb_%yz')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```